# Impedir penetración de objetos colisionando

Tags: c++, matemáticas

Llevo varios días intentando implementar un sistema de colisiones en 3D con rotaciones de figuras simétricas y por ahora tengo:

- Detección de colisiones de OBBs esferas y planos infinitos.
- Cálculo del impulso (velocidad angular y lineal).

Pero me queda idear alguna manera de impedir que los objetos penetren entre sí. Hay una serie de restrecciones a la hora de hacer esto:

- El cálculo del impulso debe ser realizado respecto a la velocidad real del objeto(si va a 5 ms y colisiona a los 2,5 metros no puedo cambiar la velocidad a 2,5 ms dado que afectaría al impulso)
- La posición de antes de la iteración anterior no puede ser modificada(no quiero que se "teletransporte" para no modificar la velocidad).

Por lo tanto la solución que se me ha ocurrido es:

- El impulso se calcula a partir de la velocidad real.
- Este impulso se suma a la velocidad a la que debería ir para no colisionar.

El cálculo de esta velocidad (que tiene componente lineal y angular) a la que debería ir es para mi la parte compleja. Tenemos una situación como la siguiente:

[image: Ilustración 1]

Lo que ando buscando es el tiempo *t* en el cual el objeto colisiona para establecerla como la velocidad tanto angular como lineal del objeto y posteriormente aplicarle a esta velocidad el impulso que se calculará respecto a la velocidad real en la que ocurrió la colisión.

Qué datos conocemos:

- Velocidad lineal.
- Velocidad angular.
- *depth*.
- Cual es el borde, plano o esquina que colisiona. En caso de ser un borde o una cara se coge como punto de colisión el punto medio de la superficie que colisiona.

Qué desconocemos:

- Punto real de colisión.
- Tiempo t en el que ocurre la colisión.

Qué buscamos:

- Las velocidades angular y lineales para que no haya penetración.

[image: Búsqueda de t]

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: El problema que tienes con esto es que no es sencillo, a priori, saber qué parte del objeto va a colisionar. Una posible solución pasaría por detectar que parte del objeto ha colisionado y chequear la trayectoria de cada elemento de dicha geometría para encontrar el elemento que colisiona primero. Una vez tienes localizado el objeto y el momento en el que colisiona puedes extraer el ángulo de impacto para hacer tus cálculos.

Comment: @eferion La parte del objeto que colisiona la se y también se que está colisionando. Actualmente de forma provisional tengo hecho una aproximación del t en el que ocurre la colisión de forma bastante tosca para seguir haciendo otras cosas de mientras. Lo que hago es ir multiplicando las velocidades por 0.9 hasta que no haya colisión. Como digo, bastante tosco, pero por ahora me hace el apaño hasta que se me ocurra o a alguien se le ocurra alguna forma de hallar ese tiempo.

Comment: @eferion el ángulo con el que colisiona también lo se dado que puedo hallar la velocidad en ese punto, cuya dirección me da ese ángulo respecto a la normal. La velocidad en ese punto es:
vpunto= velocidadLineal + velocidadAngular.Cross(punto de colisión respecto al centro del cubo), si esta velocidad la normalizo y hago el producto escalar con la normal del plano te da el coseno del ángulo que forman.

Answer (score 2):

He conseguido solucionar el problema, de forma un poco brusca, pero veo que se suele resolver de esta manera por comentarios de otros usuarios, dejo la solución por si le ayuda a alguien:

**Problema: Hacer colisiones con rotación de cualquier par de objetos, impidiendo penetración entre objetos y aplicando impulsos tantos rotacionales como lineales.**

Solución: Dados dos objetos A y B

- ¿Hay colisión? Si hay colisión tenemos que ver que punto de A está más introducido en B. En el caso de un cubo será una cara una esquina o un borde. Para caras y bordes cogemos el centro de la superficie que colisiona (lo necesitaremos para el impulso)
- Si hay colisión significa que en algún momento en este frame ha ocurrido la colisión. Debemos de hallar cual es el t: 0 < t < 1 el cual multiplicado por la velocidad angular y lineal del frame nos de sus valores para ese instante. Para ello lo que yo he hecho(seguro que hay una mejor manera) es multiplicar t*=0.8f hasta que detecte que ya no hay colisión. Si ha hecho esto 10 veces cogemos este t(para este caso sería t=0.10...).
- Respecto a los valores de w y v hallados calculamos el impulso(Como hallar el impulso: 3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development - pg.620) cuyos valores de ambos objetos guardamos.
- Aplicamos a ambos objetos las velocidades v y w que sacamos a partir de t para colocar el objeto en el momento justo anterior a la colisión. Con esto hemos resuelto la parte del frame t.
- Ahora tenemos que resolver la parte del frame t-1. Para ello multiplicamos el impulso(que será la velocidad que tenga el objeto después de la colisión) por t-1 para saber cual será la posición del objeto al terminar el frame.
- Con esto ya tenemos el frame resuelto. Por ello ponemos las velocidades a 0. Para el siguiente frame, el valor del impulso(completo) se sumará al de resto de fuerzas que afecten al objeto.